# gulp Copy from multiple locations, dont preserve structure

Tags: node.js, gulp

Im trying to copy files from multiple locations, into one central location using gulp. I dont want to preserve the directory path strucure they are being copied from EXCEPT for directories from within the one im copying from (hopefully that makes sense).

So in my example i only want to preserve any structure found in the `images` directory.

I have:

```
    var files = [
        'path/to/wp/my-mu-plugins/**/build/theme/images/**/*',
        'path/to/wptheme/build/theme/images/**/*',
        'bower_components/jquery-ui/themes/base/images/**/*',
        'bower_components/jquery-ui/themes/ui-lightness/images/**/*',
    ];

    return gulp.src(files)
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public_html/assets/images/'));
```

I have tried different combination's of altering basename, base, dir and using glob to pull them in - but I always end up with either either a flat structure or a the entire structure from where im copying from.

What combination of wizardy do i need to achieve this - or is this not possible?

Thanks =)

edit: I think my issue is with the  `path/to/wp/my-mu-plugins/**` paths, that's where the trouble starts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing to the `dest()` location gulp strips away a base path from the path of every file. If no explicit base path is provided, gulp (actually vinyl-fs) assumes everything up to the first glob to be the base path.

In your case that means that `'path/to/wp/my-mu-plugins/'` is assumed to be the base path for everything matching `'path/to/wp/my-mu-plugins/**/build/theme/images/**/*'`.

While you can specify an explicit base path using the [base option to `src()`](https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl-fs#optionsbase) this isn't of much use to you, since the base option doesn't support globbing and you don't know which or how many subdirectories match `'my-mu-plugins/**'`.

However you can use the base option to disable the default behavior and then strip everything up to and including the `/images/` folder from the path using [gulp-rename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename):

```
gulp.task('default', function() {
  return gulp.src(files, { base:'./' })
    .pipe(rename(function(path) {
      path.dirname = path.dirname.replace(/(.*)?\/images\/?/, '');
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public_html/assets/images/'));
});
```

Comment: Thank you Sven! Worked a treat! I updated to the regex to `.replace(/(.*)?(\\|\/)images(\\|\/)?/, '')` to take into account the path was using \ for path directory separators. Guessing this is my windows box fault?

Comment: Yeah, that's a Windows thing. If you want your Gulpfile to work on all platforms (in case it should ever have to run on a Linux box) you can use the nodejs [`path` module](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) instead of the regex |. Once you `var path = require('path');` the module you can get the path separator via `path.sep` which will be a \ on Windows and / on Unix systems.